# Thermodynamics with explicit math

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations

Nathaniel adeptly answers a question on thermodynamics by making the variable dependencies explicit:

[Determine the Dependence of S (Entropy) on V and T](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57177/)

Is there a thermodynamics text that is written in this same way?

Comment: Callen: THERMODYNAMICS AND AN INTRODUCTION TO THERMOSTATISTICS, I suggest the 2nd ed

Comment: Thank you.  This same reference is strongly endorsed in a related thread.  I'll check it out.